# Centralize updation of definition in SOAP UI

Tags: soapui, web-api-testing

I've done automation of API testing in SOAP UI.

I've added API request in test step for my test cases.

Now after completion of API testsuite, if there is any change in request parameter like new parameter added or removed then how do I manage testsuite?

Comment: You mean change in the request (additional xml nodes)? or updating wsdl file? or both?

Comment: @Rao - I want to reflect changes in all request with one change. Any way is acceptable.

Comment: If I understand right, the changes would be in xsd/wsdl(such as new element added /removed), hence project needs to be updated with the same and the same should be reflected in the requests well. But the issue is to update the requests while wsdls can be updated easily.

Comment: I said that there is problem updating requests because if new requests needs an element with a specific value, then there is no easy way you could achieve that unless you have a fixed request for particular step already.